# Attribute Error after adding many=True in restframework django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:

        model = Comment
        fields=('Comment','Comment_text','Comment_time','Comment_Post','Comment_User', )

class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
    model = Postovo
    fields = ('Postovo_id','Postovo_trending','comment', )
```

Models are like this

```
class Postovo(models.Model):

Postovo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
Postovo_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, related_name='posttype' ,default='1', editable=True)
Postovo_time = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=currentTimestamp, editable=True)
Postovo_link1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default='linkofimage1', editable=True)
Postovo_link2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default='linkofimage2', editable=True)
Postovo_person1=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='person1', editable=True)
Postovo_person2=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='person2', editable=True)
Postovo_hot=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='False', editable=True)
Postovo_trending=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='False', editable=True)


def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.Postovo_id)
```

Next

```
class Comment(models.Model):

Comment = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
Comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Comment_time = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=currentTimestamp)
Comment_Post = models.ForeignKey(Postovo, related_name='commentpost' ,default='1', editable=True)
Comment_User = models.ForeignKey(RegUser, related_name='commentuser' ,default='1', editable=True)
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.Comment)
```

In views

```
class Postcomment(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Postovo.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostSerializers
```

**ERROR**

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
>   field `comment` on serializer `PostSerializers`. The serializer field
>   might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
>   `Postovo` instance. Original exception text was: 'Postovo' object has
>   no attribute 'comment'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to **use the related name `commentpost` instead of `comment`** in `PostSerializers`.

```
class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    commentpost = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
    model = Postovo
    fields = ('Postovo_id','Postovo_trending','commentpost', )
```

The error is coming because there is no `comment` attribute on a `Postovo` instance. The manager for getting all the related `Comment` instances is accessible using the `related_name`  `commentpost`.

Comment: It worked :) @rahul  thank you very much actually this silly thing is not mentioned anywhere .